# global variables scope in php

Tags: php, variables, scope, global

I didn't understand this sentence from php.net:
Note:
Using global keyword outside a function is not an error. It can be used if the file is included from inside a function.

what does it mean? can anyone demonstrate briefly?

Comment: Example: `<?php global $a;` global keyword used outside a function

Comment: yes but I didn't understood the part that says it can be used if the file is included from inside a function

Answer (score 0):

**Global Variables:**

In contrast to local variables, a global variable can be accessed in any part of the program. However, in order to be modified, a global variable must be explicitly declared to be global in the function in which it is to be modified. This is accomplished, conveniently enough, by placing the keyword GLOBAL in front of the variable that should be recognized as global. Placing this keyword in front of an already existing variable tells PHP to use the variable having that name.

**Example**

```
$somevar = 15;

function addit(){
   GLOBAL $somevar;
   $somevar++;
   print "Somevar is $somevar";
}

addit();
```

**Output**

Somevar is 16

Comment: thanks but that is not what I didn't understood. I wanted to see a case that uses the global outside a function scope. and what does it mean that it can be used if the file is included from inside a function

Comment: **global** keyword also be used outside of function. **global** keyword is used in function to override the local scope. And now from inside a function means if a **global** variable is defined in some other file and you are including that file from inside a function then also you can use.

Comment: can you please give me a short example because I tried doing it without any success

Answer (score 0):

"It can be used if the file is included from inside a function" means that it will even work like this:

page.php

```
<?php
  global $d;
  $d = "HI";
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
  getpage();

  function getpage(){
     include 'page.php';
     echo $d;
  }
?>
```